# How to subscribe multiple publisher in redis rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, publish-subscribe

I am having channels which are coming dynamically from another file .I have to subscribe to all the channels.But I am not able to loop through redis subscribe

```
config=["channel1","channel2","channel3"]
config.each do |ch|
  $redis.subscribe(ch) do |on|
    #on.message......
  end
end
```

But it subscribes to the first element in loop.The "config" can vary dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple channels subscription you should do it like

```
config=["channel1","channel2","channel3"]
  $redis.subscribe(config)
end
```

Reference: [github source code](https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/98e3e7a516fc9b4609bc8ab482605f835a4de621/lib/redis/subscribe.rb)

```
def subscribe(*channels, &block)
  subscription("subscribe", "unsubscribe", channels, block)
end
```

Comment: Thousnads of thanks to you @admaliesko.Even i did the same but i havent saved my config as as Array.Instead i saved them as a string.